# Eiffel: percent character into a string

Tags: eiffel

How do I concatenate a percent `%` string to a string?

as either do not work

```
s := "%%" + s + "%"
```

I know its a [special character](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/Eiffel_programming_language_syntax#Special_characters) but don't afford it neither do I find the doc...

### UPDATE

The answer was one of my attempts, but it could stay an issue of the compiler/editor. After putting the example into the same feature, compiling, and replacing the old code the compiler did not complain anymore, but still stays as syntax coloration strange

[image]

Comment: Indeed, there was an editor issue in the IDE, this was fixed yesterday, EiffelStudio 19.11 (or next beta) will include the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same double-percent string in the second case should do the trick:

```
s := "%%" + s + "%%"
```

Comment: Thx, was one of my unsuccesful attempts, see my update, it compiled but after some code removes and replaces strangely... even after a EIFGEN remove and recompile